# How do I iterate over 2 JSON lists (mix dict and list), match specific values and print another value

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, iteration

I have 2 separate JSON-Lists (with dicts) in it.
My goal is, that I want to iterate over list2 "currentUser", grab the values, search those values in list1, and as output print the value of "firstName"

e.g.
liste2: "currentUser": 123,
liste1: "id": "123", --> "firstName": "Lisa",

```
list1 = {
    "X-API-KEY": "XyZzahZaksksXXXYYYOOO000",
    "user": {
                "email": "Lisa@BLA.com",
                "firstName": "Lisa",
                "id": "123",
    },
    "Flat": {
        "city": "Munich",
        "country": "2",
        "countryCode": "DEU",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "date": "1587671397",
        "flatmates": [
            {
                "email": "Lisa@BLA.com",
                "firstName": "Lisa",
                "id": "123",
            },
            {
                "email": "Max@BLA.com",
                "firstName": "Max",
                "id": "124",
            },
            {
                "email": "Hannah@BLA.com",
                "firstName": "Hannah",
                "id": "125",
            },
            {
                "email": "Kai@BLA.com",
                "firstName": "Kai",
                "id": "126",
            }
        ],
        "founderId": "123",
        "id": "99999",
        "image": "",
        "name": "ABC",
        "postCode": "000000",
    }
}
```

```
list2 = [
    {
        "creationDate": 1587671663,
        "currentUser": 123,
        "id": 1717134,
        "title": "Do this",
        "users": [
            124,
            126
        ]
    },
    {
        "creationDate": 1587671663,
        "currentUser": 126,
        "id": 1717134,
        "title": "Do that",
        "users": [
            123,
            125
        ]
    },
    {
        "creationDate": 1587671821,
        "currentUser": 124,
        "id": 1717134,
        "title": "Clean this",
        "users": [
            125,
            122
        ]
    },
    {
        "creationDate": 1587671801,
        "currentUser": 123,
        "id": 1717134,
        "title": "Clean that",
        "users": [
            124,
            126
        ]
    }
]
```

I am pretty new to python.
There are several mind-issues for me since there is a mix between lists and dictionaries in it and how to match/search for values for 2 separate lists/dicts

What I got so far: Iterate over the "CurrentUser"

```
for user in liste2:
    print(user["currentUser"])
```

Has anyone some approaches?

Answer (score 0):

In pure python with no other modules.

```
for user in list2:
    for mate in list1['Flat']['flatmates']:
        if user['currentUser'] == int(mate['id']):
            # You found the person now execute this code...
```

One thing to note that in your list1 you flatmates id is not a integer but a string. So you have to convert that to an int in order to compare the two.